# Difference between Element.value === "" and Element.length === 0

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure this is obvious to most people, but I somehow got stuck thinking about this. Please be kind ;)

I realised that `Element.value` returns a `String` whereas `Element.length` returns an `Int`, but I'm still not sure whether the two methods return the same values (see example).

**Toy example**

I have the following input box

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="">
```

and two separate functions with the following methods

```
---method1---
var x = document.getElementById("myInput").length;

---method2---
var y = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

`y` value would be `0`, but what would `x` value be? `null` or `0`?

In other words do

`Element.value === ""` and `Element.length === 0` express the same thing?

Comment: They don't. To get the length of the string you'd have to ask for `Element.value.length`. DOM elements have no property `length` so you get `undefined`. If you get a number for `length` it means you got an array (of DOM elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.length` will be `undefined` as its not a property. See here

```js
var properties = [];
var myObject = document.getElementById("myInput");
for (var name in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    properties.push(name);
  }
}
alert(properties.filter(function(value) {
  return value && value.length > 0 && value[0] == "l";
}).join(" \n"));
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myInput").length;
```

This statement will give you `undefined`.Because length is a property of ***Array*** , ***String*** and [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)  objects.You can't implement length property on html objects .

y will be zero if you don't input any text to the text field.Otherwise it will give you the value you wave written in the text field.If you want the length of input string try `x.value.length`

Answer (score 2):

`Element.value` returns a string on *elements* that allow *user input*. There this attribute is provided by the *system*. `Element.length` is not a property.

Various other *objects* in JavaScript do feature a property `length`. `Array`s and all arrayish objects have a `length` property. They return the length of the array. An arrayish example is a node list. This is a list of elements. The function `getElementsByTagName` returns a node list for example. You can retrieve the length of this list by using `length`. The string object also has a length property (`String.prototype.length`). It returns the length of the string. (A string is also kind of an array). See this example:

```
 alert("test"[0]);
```

This will alert `t`. So you can loop through the string as if it where an array.

To conclude: `Element.value === "" and Element.length === 0` is not the same since they don't relate to each other. `Element.value === ""` and `Element.value.length === 0` almost do the same thing. The first checks if the returned string is empty, while the second checks the length of that string. In both cases the length of the string is `0`.